# BeautifulSoup find a key value inside a code snippet inside a tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My goal is to obtain the value for the 'sitekey' from a page source. The snippet of the code is [here](http://prntscr.com/ezxrat). The page in question is [this](https://checkout.shopify.com/8112501/checkouts/302b5f7bf01cc307bdaf3eb076b96e51)

Right now, doing

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'html.parser')
soup.find('div',{"class":"field field--required"})
```

does not work since there are multiple div tags with the same class name. How would I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

```
def sitekey_search(atc_link):
    response = session.get(atc_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    sitekey = soup.select("div script")[0]
    print(sitekey)
    m = re.match("""\"(\w+)\"""", sitekey)
    if m:
        print(m.groups())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(a,'lxml')
sitekey = soup.select("div script")[0]
b = sitekey.text
print(re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', b))
```

This should do the job, the variable **a** [1st line] is the input (html),
b is only the script part and the regular expression prints everything in between quotes, in this case, the key, you can use additionally`.strip("'")`  if you want to remove the quotes from the key or `replace("'","")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
soup.select("div.field.field-required")
```

it will give you a list with the divs found.

Comment: Currently I am able to find the entire script code by using `soup.select("div script")` and it returns me a list of one object, containing the entire script. However, I am not sure how to extract the 'sitekey' value. I have tried using regex but it does not work . Please see edit above